# Struct singly linked list. Why does this not work?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct item {
    int key;
    int data;
    struct item *next;
};

struct item *head = NULL;

int main()
{
    extern void filllist(), printall();
    filllist();
    printall();
    return(0);
}


void filllist()
{
    static struct item a, b, c, d;
    head = &a;
    a.key = 5;
    a.data = 0;
    a.next = &b;
    b.key = 20;
    b.data = 2;
    b.next = &c;
    c.next = &d;
    c.key = 22;
    c.data = 6;
    d.key = 38;
    d.data = 3;
    d.next = NULL;
}

void printall()
{
    static struct item h;
    head = &h;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", h.data, h.key);
        h = h.next;
    }

}
```

For the printtall function I get an error "error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct item' from type 'struct item *'". Also is there a way to traverse through a singly linked list without a fixed for loop? I want to print out the singly linked list from fillist.

Could someone assist me on how to get printtall to work? Thank you

Comment: Where did you learn this use of `static` and `extern`? It's non-idiomatic use of the language and error prone. Anyhow, your question is off topic and the reasons are explicitly ("why doesn't this code work?") mentioned.

Comment: @axiac one of the problems is that it doesn't work, therefore it's off-topic on Code Review. Please read [our guide for SO migration](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) before you redirect users to [Codereview.SE].

Comment: @Zeta got it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning a pointer to a struct here:

```
h = h.next;
```

`h` is type `struct item` but `h.next` is a **pointer** to `struct item` so you can't set `h` equal to `h.next`

Maybe you wanted:

```
h = *h.next;
```

A better way to print the list is:

```
void printall(struct item* h)
{
    while (h != NULL) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", h->data, h->key);
        h = h->next;
    }
}
```

and call it like:

```
printall(head);
```

Besides that you should get rid of all the `static` variables.

For instance make a function to add a **single** item. Normally you would use dynamic memory (`malloc`) but here is an example without dynamic memory, i.e. all variable defined in main (and no static variables):

```
struct item* add_to_front(struct item* h, struct item* n, int key, int data)
{
    n->key = key;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = h;
    return n;
}
```

and use it like:

```
int main()
{
    struct item* head = NULL;
    struct item a, b, c;
    head = add_to_front(head, &c, 1, 2);
    head = add_to_front(head, &b, 3, 4);
    head = add_to_front(head, &a, 5, 6);
    printall(head);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your updates. I understood linked list fully in python but had a hard time translating it to C. I believe I have a better understanding now thanks to your answer.